# von Neumann algebra of canonical commutation relations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-mechanics, weyl-algebra

In quantum mechanics we have position and momentum operators $P$ and $Q$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ in the usual way. I'm wondering what the von Neumann algebra generated by the bounded functions of $P$ and $Q$ is. I.e., what is
$$
\{f(Q), f(P)\,\vert\,f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})\}''?
$$
I have a hunch that the answer may have something to do with the [Wigner-Weyl transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform), but (to my surprise) I have not been able to find any reference treating this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C$^*$-algebra generated by the exponentials $e^{isQ}$ and $e^{itP}$, $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$, is the CCR algebra. The von Neumann algebra they generate in this representation is all of $B(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$. That is because  $e^{isQ}$ is multiplication by $e^{isx}$ and $e^{itP}$ is translation by $t$. Any operator that commutes with multiplication by $e^{isx}$ for all $s$ is a multiplication operator, and the only multiplication operators that commute with all translations are scalar multiples of the identity. So the result follows from the double commutant theorem.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have encountered the result that $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra of $B(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ before. So my understanding now is: $L^\infty \subset {L^\infty}' \subset {L^\infty}'' = L^\infty$, and I think it is not too hard to show that trigonometric polynomials are weakly dense in $L^\infty$. Very nice!

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.